# i have an error while inserting the values what i did

Tags: php, sql, insert

help me with this code i am new to php

```
<?php 
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","test");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
    $sql="INSERT INTO registration(fname,designation,emailid,
address,phonenumber)VALUES('".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['designation']."','".$_POST['ema
    lid']."', '".$_POST['address']."','".$_POST['phonenumber']."')";
    echo $sql;
     $result=mysql_query($conn,$sql);
echo $result;
    }
    else{
        echo "Error";
    }

    ?>
```

its a registration page getting values and inserting it in the table...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: $result = mysql_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: this is the error i am getting : mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: have you escaped the values being inserted into the database? Your very prone to SQL injection using this code along with the mysql_ function

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: So wrong on so many levels: use of [the deprecated MySQL API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), wide open to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).  May I suggest you take a step back and - as @TimothyChoi also suggests, learn about the *proper ways* to write such code?

Comment: @fvu its for starting study purpose thats it

Comment: @Ray even more so then: invest your time in learning how to do things ***properly***.  I understand you want to see something on screen, but trust the people here, what your doing now will get you in the best case nowhere, worst case in deep trouble because due to the injection issues your site was defaced and maybe used for illegal purposes.

Comment: yes now i understand i will take some more time and put effort in learning thanks for your valuable comments @fvu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) which is a good tutorial for inserting data (from a form etc.) to a mysql database.

Also: be aware of sql-injection and prevent it. here is a tutorial on how to do this: [link](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)

Comment: thx @xeraphim i will look through it

Answer (score 1):

You have the parameters around the wrong way here:

```
$result=mysql_query($conn,$sql);
```

Try

```
$result=mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));
```

Side notes:

- Don't use `mysql_*()` functions: they're deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` versions instead.
- You should escape your user inputs with `mysql_real_escape_string()` to protect against SQL Injection attacks. Consider using prepared statements with `mysqli_()` instead.

Comment: still problem continues values not inserted in table

Comment: If you've followed my suggestion I doubt that the _original_ problem continues. You may be seeing a different problem now but you haven't posted your HTML or a new error message so it's going to b difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have readable code, set the `$_POST[]` values to a variable, and then pass them to the query, it's not different in fact but this is more easy and clean.:

```
<?php 
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","test");

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        { 
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $designation = $_POST['designation'];
        $emailid = $_POST['emailid'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO registration(fname,designation,emailid,address,phonenumber)";
        $sql .="VALUES('$fname', '$designation', '$emailid', '$address', '$phonenumber')";
        echo $sql;
         $result=mysql_query($conn,$sql);
       echo $result;
        }
        else{
            echo "Error";
        }
    ?>
```

you hade a typing mistake in `$_POST['emailid']`...
and you can select your database with this:

```
mysql_select_db('your db name');
```

put this line after your connection variable means `$conn`

and this is wrong:

```
$result = mysql_query ($conn, $sql)
```

you have to set the query first:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
```

Comment: Warning:mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string

Comment: no issue in sql code even here.. but why to store values in extra variables & put some load on server.

Comment: did you fix the mysql_query? look at the end of my answer...

Comment: ya i did that too now there is no warning but not inserting also

Comment: would you show your html page here?

Comment: and did you use `mysql_select_db` line?